# perl comparing files to find lines that are missing from one of the files

Tags: perl

```
/* format of the files:123|0|15454215|desc|11/30/2012|N|Y|
open FILE1, "/home/1.txt" or die $!;
open FILE2, "/home/2.txt" or die $!;

while (<FILE2>) {
  @old_item = split(/\|/);
  if (<FILE1> !~ /$old_item[0]\|$old_item[1]\|$old_item[2]/) {
    print "$old_item[0]|$old_item[1]|$old_item[2]|$old_item[3]|$old_item[4]|$old_item[5]|$old_item[6]|DE|\n";
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is opening two files then comparing them to find any lines that are in the first and not in the second then outputting a line with some old and new info.

But what's happening is once it finds a line that isn't in the second file but is in the first it starts printing every line. What am I doing wrong and is there an easier way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use `diff -u` or some such? If you want a Perl solution, check out [Algorithm::Diff](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Algorithm%3a%3aDiff).

Comment: That a good idea but for this I'm unable to use any add-on Modules. (has to do with the company I work for)

Comment: @Bill, So if I post my code on SO, it's ok, but it I post it on CPAN, it's not? WTF! Well, I'm too lazy to copy Algorithm::Diff here, so I guess someone else will have to do it.

Comment: I completely agree. To get something add though I have to write up why we need it, and submit it to my manager. And that's not something I want to do for this.

Comment: @Bill, Well, tried to copy it here, but it was over the maximum size limit.

Comment: So copy and paste from Algorithm::Diff.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on is since you are reading each file line-by-line, an additional line causes all lines to be off (since one of the files will be one line ahead in its count, so to speak). If you still want to pursue writing your own perl code for this, it may help to load the files into an array fist and compare that way, incrementing indices only when you need to.

Answer (score 1):

There is a module for comparing the two files in the perl.

ALgorithm::Diff module,

Algorithm::Diff - Compute `intelligent' differences between two files / lists,which will compare the two files line by line and checks it fully.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your data would be useful.  But making an educated guess.. walk through this with a debugger, and I think you'll see what's going on is that once you find a missing line, you then skip to the next line of input on *both* streams.

Now you've got an off-by-one problem for the rest of the input.

Comment: What's moving the <FILE1> stream? Aren't I just checking to see if the String is in the second file? What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason that is happening is that one it finds a difference the lines are no long synchronized.

You will have to add some code to search for matching lines to re-synchronize the file readers.